# How to Get Two option value by 1 select?

Tags: php, mysql

Please modify this code so that i will get 2 option value from this code

```
    <select name="student_class1" class="input-xlarge" >
     <option value="null">--Select Class---</option>
    <?php $sel_service = "select * from all_services where school_id='$school_id'";
      $sel_service= mysql_query($sel_service);
       while($display_class= mysql_fetch_assoc($sel_service))
       {  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $display_class['sub_cat_id']; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($display_class['sub_cat_name']); ?></option>
       <?php } ?>
```

student_class1 giving me value sub_cat_id
i want 
student_class2  will give me sub_cat_name
iwant both values by one select
plz modify it
i already spent my whole sunday on this problem

Answer (score 0):

something like?

```
<form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
<select name="student_class1" class="input-xlarge" >
<?php 
    $sel_service = "select * from all_services where school_id='$school_id'";
    $sel_service= mysql_query($sel_service);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel_service)) {
?>
        <option value="null">--Select Class---</option> 
        <option value="<?php echo $row['sub_cat_id']; ?>"></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['sub_cat_name']; ?>"></option>
<?php 
     }
 ?> 
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: from this code iam gettin student_class1 = sub_cat_id , but what about student_class2 =?

Comment: i want student_class2 give me sub_cat_name

Comment: @user3237236 I dont understand ? Do you want 2 different select forms one with student_class1 and one for student_class2 ?